Add environmental texture to Autodesk Forge Viewer
How to add an environmental texture to Autodesk Forge Viewer v6.0?
In Three.js, you can assign a texture to the scene background and environment, so how can I do the same in APS viewer?
I'm not seeking a skybox, I need an environmental texture that can be reflected on the model in the viewer.
I want to use something like the following code:
const envTexture = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader().load([
'/content/img/px_50.png',
'/content/img/nx_50.png',
'/content/img/py_50.png',
'/content/img/ny_50.png',
'/content/img/pz_50.png',
'/content/img/nz_50.png',
]);

envTexture.mapping = THREE.CubeReflectionMapping;

But again I want similar result for release 71 of three,js.

Does this answer your question? How to set up skybox in Autodesk Forge

First, you should use the Viewer v7 instead of v6, which was replaced in 2019!
I assume that what you want is to create a 3d background (skybox) and this question has already been asked a few times How to set up a skybox in Autodesk Forge
If you only want a flat image as background, this answer can also be useful Transparent background viewer
